# my laravel route return 404 error but route exists?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing

I'm using laravel 5.6 and i've just started create api using Laravel framework and I'm having an issue with routing.

The only route that's working like that

> http://my-domain-name.com/index.php/api/my-api-name

if i romve index.php from my url :-

> http://my-domain-name.com/api/my-api-name

then i got **404 not found** error.

How can i fix this?

Comment: modify your `.htaccess` file: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-remove-indexphp-from-url?page=1

Comment: i modify my .htaccess but i got same error...@НиколайЛубышев

Comment: restart apache service
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: thats original
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls

Comment: `If you use Apache to serve your Laravel application, be sure to enable the  mod_rewrite module`

Comment: `$ sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out your Apache config, it have to be like that:

```
<VirtualHost laravel.dev:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public"
  ServerAdmin laravel.dev
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```